# CMake JNI error

Tags: java-native-interface, cmake

I've written a binding C++ class that calls java from C++. I am trying to compile the binding class using CMake (because the tool that will use the binding class uses CMake).

However I receive the following error:

```
CMakeFiles/JNIWrapper.dir/JNIWrapper.cpp.o: In function `createVM(JavaVM_**)':
JNIWrapper.cpp:(.text+0x52): undefined reference to `JNI_CreateJavaVM'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [JNIWrapper] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/JNIWrapper.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Here is my CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.6)

project(AProject)

FIND_PACKAGE(JNI REQUIRED)

SET(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -I/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-amd64/include -I/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-amd64/include/linux -L/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/amd64/server")

SET(CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS "-ljvm")

# add the binary tree directory to the search path for include files
include_directories(${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR})
include_directories(${JNI_INCLUDE_DIRS})

# add the executable
add_executable (JNIWrapper JNIWrapper.cpp)
```

Any suggestion is appreciated.

PS: I have tried to compile it using the traditional way and by writing a makefile. I followed that example and wrote the CMakeLists.txt script above.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The following `CMakeLists.txt` sketches the steps required to build a sample JNI project with CMake:

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 3.0)

find_package(Java REQUIRED)
find_package(JNI REQUIRED)
include(UseJava)

enable_testing()
project (JNIFoo)

# compile JNIFoo.java to class file
set(CMAKE_JAVA_COMPILE_FLAGS "-source" "1.6" "-target" "1.6")
add_jar(JNIFoo JNIFoo.java)
get_target_property(_jarFile JNIFoo JAR_FILE)
get_target_property(_classDir JNIFoo CLASSDIR)

# generate JNIFoo.h stub
set (_stubDir "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}")
add_custom_command(
    OUTPUT JNIFoo.h
    COMMAND ${Java_JAVAH_EXECUTABLE} -verbose
        -classpath ${_classDir}
        -d ${_stubDir}
        -jni JNIFoo
    DEPENDS JNIFoo
    )

# generate libfoo.jnilib
include_directories(${JNI_INCLUDE_DIRS} ${_classDir} ${_stubDir})
add_library(foo MODULE foo.c JNIFoo.h)
set_target_properties(foo PROPERTIES SUFFIX ".jnilib")
target_link_libraries(foo ${JNI_LIBRARIES})

# add test to run JNIFoo
add_test(NAME TestJNIFoo
    COMMAND ${Java_JAVA_EXECUTABLE}
    -Djava.library.path=${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}
    -cp ${_jarFile} JNIFoo)
```

The file `JNIFoo.java` contains a Java class that declares a function in `foo.c` as a native method `nativeFoo`. `foo.c` contains the C implementation of the method `nativeFoo`.

The CMake function [add_jar](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/UseJava.html) compiles the Java class to a jar file and, as a side effect, creates a class file which needs to be passed as an input to the `javah` C stub file generator executable. A custom command is used to invoke `javah` to generate the stub header `JNIFoo.h` as an output file.

Because Java uses `System.loadLibrary` to load JNI libraries at runtime, the JNI library must be generated as a `MODULE` library using the CMake command [add_library](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_library.html). Adding `JNIFoo.h` as a source file ensures that `JNIFoo.h` will be created before the library is compiled. The compiled JNI library needs to be linked with the JDK JNI libraries contained in the variable `JNI_LIBRARIES`. `JNI_INCLUDE_DIRS` contains the the JNI include dirs to use.

Finally, a test is added to run the class JNIFoo with the JVM. The system property `java.library.path` must be set to the directory containing the generated JNI library `libfoo.jnilib`.

Comment: This is useful, but didn't find the $JAVA_HOME/include folders without doing: include_directories(${JAVA_INCLUDE_PATH} ${_classDir} ${_stubDir} $ENV{JAVA_HOME}/include/linux $ENV{JAVA_HOME}/include/  )

Comment: For Linux you may want to use `${JAVA_INCLUDE_PATH} ${JAVA_INCLUDE_PATH2}`. The second include path is for jni_md.h, that is included from jni.h in Linux

Comment: The variable `JNI_INCLUDE_DIRS` contains all necessary directories to use for JNI compilation. I have updated the answer.