# How to create a proper CMakeLists.txt for JNI and C++ code?

Tags: java, c++, cmake, compilation, java-native-interface

**My Goal** :

I am trying to build a java and C++ interface of a simple project to check whether a number is Even or Odd. The java code should generate C++ header files and then I would write function definitions for the java function from inside C++ and build a library (.so) file. Later, I will run the java code to print output generated by C++. For achieving this, I wrote a simple java class and then the C++ member function using [this tutorial](https://www3.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/java/JavaNativeInterface.html).

My code is very trivial. I have reproduced it below:

**OddNumCheck.java**

```
public class OddNumCheck {
   static {
      System.loadLibrary("odd_num"); // libodd_num.so (MacOS/ Unix)
   }
 
   // Declare a native method odd_test() that receives an int and prints to the console whether it is odd or even
   private native String odd_test(int num);
 
   // Test Driver
   public static void main(String args[]) {
      System.out.println("In the Java program the given input number is " + new OddNumCheck().odd_test(3));
   }
}
```

**OddNumCheck.h**

```
/* DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE - it is machine generated */
#include <jni.h>
/* Header for class OddNumCheck */

#ifndef _Included_OddNumCheck
#define _Included_OddNumCheck
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif
/*
 * Class:     OddNumCheck
 * Method:    odd_test
 * Signature: (I)Ljava/lang/String;
 */
JNIEXPORT jstring JNICALL Java_OddNumCheck_odd_1test
  (JNIEnv *, jobject, jint);

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
#endif
```

**OddNumCheck.cpp**

```
#include <jni.h>
#include "OddNumCheck.h"

JNIEXPORT jstring

/*!
 * @brief The odd_test function is a JNI function which takes an input integer from a java function odd_test() inside
 * java a class OddNumCheck, and returns a string saying whether the passed integer is Odd or Even
 * @param num a Java integer of type jint
 * @return a java string with one of the two possibilities "Odd" or "Even"
 * */
JNICALL Java_OddNumCheck_odd_1test(JNIEnv *env, jobject obj, jint num) {
    jstring num_type;
    if (num % 2 == 0) {
        num_type = env->NewStringUTF("Even");
    } else {
        num_type = env->NewStringUTF("Odd");
    }
    return num_type;
}
```

This is my project structure:

```
OddNumCheck
 |_ CMakeLists.txt
 |_ OddNumCheck.cpp
 |_ OddNumCheck.h
 |_ OddNumCheck.java
```

I was able to compile the code and generate a lib (.so) file and then print the output to the console using the non-cmake method (typing manual compile instructions in the terminal). Now I am trying to package things into a nice and clean CMakeLists.txt file which would allow me to do everything easily in one shot.

So I followed [this CMakeLists.txt](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19034458/10019073) file that appears to be very relevant to what I am looking for and followed the instructions in it.

The following is my *CMakeLists.txt*:

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 3.0)
project (OddNumCheck)

find_package(Java REQUIRED)
find_package(JNI REQUIRED)
if (JNI_FOUND)
    message (STATUS "JNI_INCLUDE_DIRS=${JNI_INCLUDE_DIRS}")
    message (STATUS "JNI_LIBRARIES=${JNI_LIBRARIES}")
endif()
include(UseJava)

enable_testing()

# compile JNIFoo.java to class file
set(CMAKE_JAVA_COMPILE_FLAGS "-source" "1.6" "-target" "1.6")
add_jar(OddNumCheck OddNumCheck.java)
get_target_property(_jarFile OddNumCheck JAR_FILE)
get_target_property(_classDir OddNumCheck CLASSDIR)

# generate JNIFoo.h stub
set (_stubDir "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}")
add_custom_command(
        OUTPUT OddNumCheck.h
        COMMAND ${Java_JAVAH_EXECUTABLE} -verbose
        -classpath ${_classDir}
        -d ${_stubDir}
        -jni OddNumCheck
        DEPENDS OddNumCheck
)

# generate libfoo.jnilib
include_directories(${JNI_INCLUDE_DIRS} ${_classDir} ${_stubDir})
add_library(libodd_num MODULE OddNumCheck.cpp OddNumCheck.h)
set_target_properties(libodd_num PROPERTIES SUFFIX ".so")
target_link_libraries(libodd_num ${JNI_LIBRARIES})

# add test to run JNIFoo
add_test(NAME TestOddNumCheck
        COMMAND ${Java_JAVA_EXECUTABLE}
        -Djava.library.path=${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}
        -cp ${_jarFile} OddNumCheck)
```

Unfortunately, my CMake does not compile. I get the following errors (from CLion IDE):

```
====================[ Build | all | Debug ]=====================================
/usr/local/bin/cmake --build /mnt/f/sandbox/OddNumCheck/cmake-build-debug --target all -- -j 6
[ 50%] Built target OddNumCheck
[ 66%] Generating OddNumCheck.h
make[2]: Java_JAVAH_EXECUTABLE-NOTFOUND: Command not found
CMakeFiles/libodd_num.dir/build.make:61: recipe for target 'OddNumCheck.h' failed
make[2]: *** [OddNumCheck.h] Error 127
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:104: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/libodd_num.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/libodd_num.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:94: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

**UPDATE**:

I also tried this [CMakeLists.txt](https://github.com/thefangbear/JNI-By-Examples/blob/master/CMakeLists.txt) file. It is also not helpful.

Comment: It seems your `find_package(Java REQUIRED)` CMake command did not find everything. Specifically, the [`Java_JAVAH_EXECUTABLE`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/FindJava.html) variable is not properly defined. Your CMake should really check for that after calling `find_package()`, and return an error if `Java_JAVAH_EXECUTABLE` or other such variables are not found.

Comment: Recent JDKs stopped shipping `javah`, but there is a `-h` argument to `javac` instead.

Comment: @Botje Ahh, perhaps that is one solution: Modify the custom command to use `${Java_JAVAC_EXECUTABLE} -h` instead?

Comment: `-h ${_stubDir}` , I think.

Comment: @Botje When I tried this suggestion, it seems like the suggestion clears the problem with `Java_JAVAH_EXECUTABLE`. But there is a problem in the next step

```[ 66%] Generating OddNumCheck.h
error: invalid flag: -jni
Usage: javac <options> <source files>```

Comment: You need to pass that flag *as you are compiling*, so somewhere in the bowels of `add_jar`.

Comment: Is it something like `cmake .. && make -j4 javac -cp <PROJECT_DIR_NAME>` ?